# How to make a shadow effect on a image view?

Tags: ios, uiview, calayer, shadow, user-experience

I'd like to make a shadow effect on a view just like the one in the Podcasts app. Take a look at the picture below.

Since I know how to make a shadow effect on a view with a mono color, I thought I could nail it by using the clear color for a shadow color to achieve the same thing. But, it didn't do.

Have you ever struck the same issues as this?
If so, how did you do it?
If not, what do you think my options are to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: What you see there is not a shadow but actually the same image blown up with a blur effect on

Comment: It's more a blur effect than a Shadow. Shadow are of "one" color.

Answer (score -1):

Play around with these properties till you achieve your desired results:

```
    imageView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.rgb(180,180,180).cgColor
    imageView.layer.shadowOpacity = 3
    imageView.layer.shadowOffset.width = 2
    imageView.layer.shadowOffset.height = 3
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 8
```